# Graphic spot appearing on the screen when customizing UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, customization, uiactionsheet

I have a graphic white spot appearing on the screen when I customize `UIActionSheet`.

The graphic white spot disappear when I set *background to any other color than transparent...

Screenshot:

[image]

and here is my code :

```
- (void) customisingActionSheet
{

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                            delegate:nil
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                              destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];

    UIView *background = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 315)];
    background.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [actionSheet addSubview:background];

    self.customActionSheet = actionSheet;



    UIButton *cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(15, 111, 290, 45);
    [cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelButtonClicked:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cancelButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;
    [cancelButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cancelButton.backgroundColor = darkGrey;
    cancelButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    cancelButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size: 17];
    [self.customActionSheet addSubview: cancelButton];

    UIButton *chooseFromLibrary = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    chooseFromLibrary.frame = CGRectMake(15, 52, 290, 45);
    [chooseFromLibrary addTarget:self action:@selector(emailResultsTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    chooseFromLibrary.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;
    [chooseFromLibrary setTitle:@"Choose from Library" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [chooseFromLibrary setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:53/255.0f green:53/255.0f blue:53/255.0f alpha:1.0f] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    chooseFromLibrary.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    chooseFromLibrary.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    chooseFromLibrary.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"Helveticaneue" size: 17];
    [self.customActionSheet addSubview: chooseFromLibrary];

    UIButton *takePicture = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    takePicture.frame = CGRectMake(15, 0, 290, 45);
    [takePicture addTarget:self action:@selector(emailResultsTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    takePicture.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;
    [takePicture setTitle:@"Take picture" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [takePicture setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:53/255.0f green:53/255.0f blue:53/255.0f alpha:1.0f] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    takePicture.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    takePicture.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    takePicture.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"Helveticaneue" size: 17];
    [self.customActionSheet addSubview: takePicture];


    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [self.customActionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 315)];
}
```

Anyone has a solution for it?
Many thanks.

Comment: The solution is not to abuse `UIActionSheet` in a way that isn't supported by Apple. Find some 3rd party library or class that provides a customizable replacement for `UIActionSheet`.

Comment: What happens if you don't add the background view at all? What's the background view for?

Comment: @MarcusAdams without background the result is exactly the same.

Comment: Well, you're not getting anything out the `UIActionSheet`, so try a regular `UIView` with a semi-transparent background.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I will do so. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`UIActionSheet`** is not designed to be subclassed, **nor should you add views** to its hierarchy. If you need to present a sheet with more customization than provided by the `UIActionSheet` API, you can create your own and present it modally with `presentViewController:animated:completion:`.

Based on: [UIActionSheet Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiactionsheet_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: You probably don't want to create a view controller and present it modally. This would only work if you are using a navigation controller and only on certain iOS versions. Just use a sub view.